# How do intersection types work in conjunction with polymorphic this and generics?

Tags: typescript, this

The following code snippet doesn't compile, and I don't understand why. Sorry that it's a little verbose, this is the smallest MWE I could find.

```
interface Num {
    num: number;
}

class Base {
    num?: number;
    base(): this {
        return this;
    }

    addNum(): this & Num {
        this.num = 1;
        return this as this & Num;
    }
}

function unwrapNum<B extends Base>(base: B): B & Num {
    return base.addNum().base();
}
```

it fails with error:

```
Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'B & Num'.
  Type 'Base' is not assignable to type 'B & Num'.
    Type 'Base' is not assignable to type 'B'.
      'Base' is assignable to the constraint of type 'B', but 'B' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'.
        Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'Num'.
          Type 'Base' is not assignable to type 'Num'.
            Types of property 'num' are incompatible.
              Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

My understanding is the input type is `B` after calling `addNum` it should turn into `B & Num` which it seems to if I break out that assignment. However, when I call `base()` on that, the result doesn't have type `B & Num` as I expect / want, but instead just `B`, which implies that something isn't working as expected. My hunch is that this has to do with the polymorphic this, e.g. `(B & Num).base()` does not have type `B & Num`.

However, if I remove the generics with something like:

```
const base = new Base();
const numed: Base & Num = base.addNum();
const numed2: Base & Num = numed.base();
```

that works just fine, so it feels like it's a combination of the generic Base, polymorphic this, and intersection type.

Stangely, this does compile if wrapped in another generic:

```
function unwrapNum<B extends Base>(base: B): B & Num {

    function helper<BN extends B & Num>(b: BN): BN {
        return b.base();
    }

    return helper(base.addNum());
}
```

Thanks Aleksey L. for the smaller MWQ

Comment: Here's one example where it breaks: `unwrapNum` can be called with something like `class FooBase extends Base { num: 2 = 2 }`

Comment: @AlekseyL. True, but that shouldn't actually break it, the result is still `FooBase & Num` which just happens to be the same as FooBase. Also, it doesn't explain the error message which is specifically about not being able to assign undefined to number.

Comment: Yes, I see. I was referring to `this.num = 1`. Nevermind. Here's simpler reproduction of the problem: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2yDeBYAKGWORCwC5SsAjaAbkIF9DCEAbOAZ0+QCEuU+IiTKYA-JVG0oDYcWoCAFAEpKYABbAeQkruRQIYdFBDINW2buYFCuuABN7GTCrWaeAMjRZctvcXNOADpRZABeZABGS399Q2NTQOQuM3dkL2cY4mtrQhh0EAQwYAB7UwKAdyg4AAdnAB5eZAgAD0gQex5+TggAPkUC0pBKXlU+dO9sHRIEMs4wZGpw5EGyoIcnLBUghR6VLLijE0XZRiA . After call to `.base()` it looses `& Num` part - this explains the error we see above. Interesting that it doesn't happen when using `Container `